How to get the xpath of button that contains text in appium
//android.widget.Button[@text="Flu Shot (Regular) Getting your flu shot is one of the best ways you can protect yourself, your loved ones, and your community from the flu.   Book now for up to 6 people. Appointments will take about 5-15 minutes per person. Book an appointment to get your flu shot from an Injection-Trained Pharmacy Professional.   Eligibility: Pharmacists can administer flu shots to children aged: 5 and older in Yukon, Alberta, Saskatchewan and PEI; 4 and older in British Columbia; 2 and older in Ontario, Manitoba, New Brunswick, and Newfoundland. Flu shot administration for children under the age of 5 may vary from Pharmacy to Pharmacy—please confirm with your location before booking. CONTINUE"]

I need to click on continue button in this.
Tried few xpaths:
//*[ends-with(@text,‘(CONTINUE)’)]
//*[@class="android.widget.Button" and @index=7]
//android.widget.Button[@text="CONTINUE"]

Try with
//*[contains(@text, 'CONTINUE')]
